# Lightweight recording software for Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-recording

Since the computers I'm looking into aren't the greatest (3gb ram, core2duo) I'd naturally need a lightweight recording software. (Something not CPU heavy)

(Sorry for being vague, I meant a screen recording software that isn't cpu intensive)

Comment: Recording what? Audio, screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit vague, but I assume you mean video screen recording.

I use [simple screen recorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/). I don't know what how light-weight you want it, but simple screen recorder doesn't take up a lot of CPU (at least on my computer, not sure about your's if it is older technology).

Best of luck to you!